# Binary shift on string in Python

Tags: python, binary

Given a binary string, shift it by the amount given.

I am having trouble understanding why this code fails, I convert the string into binary then perform the shift, but I get unsupported operand type(s) for <<: 'str' and 'int'.

I think I am converting the binary string incorrectly but am not sure how else to do it.

```py
def insertt(num, numb, shift):

  num = bin(int(num, 2) << shift)
  numb = bin(int(numb))
  print(bin(int(num, 2) | bin(int(numb, 2))



a = '10000000000'
b = '1001'
c = 2
insertt(a, b, c)
```

Expected result is just the shift.

Thank you

Comment: `bin` returns a string. I am guessing you want `bin(int(a, 2) << 2)` (ie do the shift on the `int`, then convert to the binary string representation). Or do you want to do a circular shift? Please show some example inputs/outputs.

Comment: I am trying to 1- convert the string to a binary number, 2 do a logical shift on it to the left (Non circular)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to shift your  binary string  before using bin :

```
def insertt(num, shift):

  num = bin(int(num, 2) << shift)
  print(num)

a = '10000000000'
c = 2
insertt(a, c)

# output: 0b1000000000000
```